# Exported CDF file does not include GeoGraphics

Tags: cdf-format, geography

I'm trying to display a map on manipulate and the case is .nb files shows it but when I export it to .cdf this format not show the GeoGraphics map

```
    routesPosition = 
  Import["http://sitiopruebamathematica.altervista.org/rutas.xml", 
   "XML"];
rp = Cases[routesPosition, XMLElement["ROW", _, _], Infinity] /. 
    XMLElement[_, _, {val_}] :> val /. 
   XMLElement["ROW", _, list_] :> list;

Manipulate[

 names = Insert[rp[[All, 1]], "All", 1];
 point = ToExpression[rp[[All, 2]]];

 If[route == "All",
  ruta = "all routes";,
  p = Position[names, route][[1, 1]];
    If[NumberQ[p] == True,
    ruta = p - 1;,
   ruta = p
   ];
  ];


 Row[{names, "\n", rp[[All, 1]], "\n", routesPosition[[1]], "\n", 
   route, "\n", ruta}],
 Control@{route, names, PopupMenu},
 TrackedSymbols :> {route, names, point},
 Initialization :> (ruta = "all routes")
 ]
```

This simple example in which you cannot cange anything, I made it to test if geographics works, if y delete `Red,Thick,Line[GeoPosition[point[[All]]]]` the .cdf file show it but if it stay at file .cdf file not show any map, and also I notice that cdf not make the import but the array that contains the route names is full

[image: this picture shows the .nb file output]

[image: this picture shows the .cdf file output]

fist picture show .nb file output and secon .cdf file output

Comment: Okay, making some proves i found that if toy put a {lat, lon} directly on GeoPosition[] works percfetly, but if you put it in a variable and after you use that variabel on GeoPosition not work

Comment: `rp` is not saved between sessions. You have to use `Initialization` or `SaveDefinitions`.

Comment: p.s. I still can't use your code without prompting errors. are you able to run this code on fresh notebook.

Comment: yes, in my notebook can running and the output es the firs image, so it seems to do what I want

Comment: I'm getting an error: Manipulate::vstype: ControlType -> PopupMenu is not supported for the variable specification {route$$,names}. ControlType -> InputField will be used instead. >>

Comment: I mean I just get it , i close mathematica and open it again and give me that error, but it the first time

Comment: It's because `route` has no initial value. But the main problem is related to what I've said in first comment.

Comment: Even adding a initial value for route at Initialization block it gives me the same error

Comment: Manipulate controlers are not waiting for initialization, only the body does, so you have to do this earlier.