# Specifying a PopupMenu in a Manipulate expression

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

In my previous question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89412/exported-cdf-file-does-not-include-geographics?noredirect=1#comment244548_89412), I had a problem with showing GeoGraphics in a CDF document, but thanks to other users, I was able to solve it. But the code I wrote to test my work gave an error. I tried the code again and I got the same error.

> Manipulate::vstype: ControlType -> PopupMenu is not supported for the variable specification {route$$,names}. ControlType -> InputField will be used instead

I tried to initialize the `route` variable in the `Initialization` option, but my code still does not work. Any Ideas?

```
Manipulate[
 If[route == "All",
    ruta = "all routes",
    p = Position[names, route][[1, 1]];
    If[NumberQ[p] == True,
       ruta = p - 1,
       ruta = p
    ]
 ];

 Row[{names, "\n", rp[[All, 1]], "\n", routesPosition[[1]], "\n", 
   route, "\n", ruta}],

 Control @ {route, names},
 TrackedSymbols :> {route, names, point},

 Initialization :> (
    routesPosition = 
    Import["http://sitiopruebamathematica.altervista.org/rutas.xml", 
     "XML"];
    rp = Cases[routesPosition, XMLElement["ROW", _, _], Infinity] /. 
      XMLElement[_, _, {val_}] :> val /. 
     XMLElement["ROW", _, list_] :> list;
    names = Insert[rp[[All, 1]], "All", 1];
    point = ToExpression[rp[[All, 2]]];
    ruta = "all routes";
    route = names[[1]];
   ),
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 SaveDefinitions -> True,
 ControlType -> PopupMenu
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't run your code, so I can't offer you a working modification to your code, but only offer advice.

Popup menus can't be specified in the way you have tried to do it. Here is an example of a demonstration with a popup menu specified in the conventional way (which is simple). I hope you can adapt it to your needs.

```
With[{maxK = 3},
  With[{lbls = TraditionalForm /@ Table[Sin[k "t" + "ϕ"], {k, maxK}]},
    With[{rules = Thread[Rule[Range @ maxK, lbls]]}, 
      Manipulate[
        Plot[Sin[k t + ϕ], {t, 0, 2 π}], 
        {{k, 2, "function"}, rules, PopupMenu},
        {ϕ, 0., 1. π, π/8., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]]]
```

[image: demo]