# How to use a PopupMenu in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, output-formatting, formatting, options

I need to build a Manipulate to show one of several functions in 3D.  The functions should be selected in the Manipulate box using a PopupMenu, but the documentation isn't very helpfull on this.  So how should I define the Popup in the Manipulate code to select a function (by its name) ?  Here's a MWE to work with, which uses a simple *inadequate* checkbox :

```
Surface1 = SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}];
Surface2 = ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 0}, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}];

Manipulate[
    Show[{If[p, Surface1, Surface2]},
    PlotRange -> All,
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}
    ],
    Row[{Spacer[0], Control[{{p, False, "sphere"}, {False, True}}]}],
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom
]
```

Comment: Have you seen [Specifying a PopupMenu in a Manipulate expression](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89508/specifying-a-popupmenu-in-a-manipulate-expression)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want or the best you can do but...

```
Surface1 = SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}];
Surface2 = ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 0}, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}];

Manipulate[
 Show[surf, PlotRange -> All,
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}],
 {{surf, Surface1}, {Surface1 -> "Surface1", Surface2 -> "Surface2"}, 
  PopupMenu},
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow!  That appears to be it !  It's so simple !  I'm studying this right away, thanks a lot !  :-)

Comment: Ok, it's working, but what about two sets of objects ?  I mean if you want to show a surface and a vector if you select option 1, and show another surface with another vector, if you select option 2 ?

Comment: Forget it, I've found it.  It's almost "trivial".